# How to create a code signing certificate in PFX/password format with csrgenerator.com?

Tags: ssl, code-signing, pfx

I'm trying to renew my code signing certificate, which is used as a PFX (and password).

Godaddy, our cert provider [provides instructions](https://www.godaddy.com/help/windows-generate-csr-for-code-or-driver-signing-certificate-7282) on generating a CSR, however this appears to be outdated for Windows 10.

I called godaddy and they told me to use csrgenerator.com to generate something like:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
foo
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----

-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
bar
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I then pasted the CSR into godaddy's site and they said once the cert is rekeyed, I can download .pem and .spc  files.

How am I supposed to create a PFX with password from this?  If I understand correctly, I need to generate a CSR from **my** machine.  The godaddy rep assure me that csrgenerator.com is generating a csr for my machine, but I've no idea how it is getting added to my certificates using MMC, much less how am I going to export the cert to a PFX.  Even though I have the private key section, I don't see it being applied anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question was asked several months ago, but I wanted to include a reply in case it helps anyone in the future.  (I came across this post when I was trying to accomplish the same thing)

Follow these instructions to create a PFX file from the GoDaddy certificate:
https://www.godaddy.com/help/windows-install-codedriver-signing-certificate-and-create-pfx-file-2698

If you cannot complete these steps because the PFX option is greyed out, then the CSR generated does now allow the private key to be exported.  I'm pretty sure the GoDaddy instructions linked in the question above are only for Windows Server.  However, I was able to complete the following instructions on Windows 10 to generate a CSR that allowed the private key to be exported: http://www.entrust.net/knowledge-base/technote.cfm?tn=8924